# Updating Column chart dynamically throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, scichart

We have a Donut chart and when a slice is clicked on the donut chart we would like to update the values in the ColumnChart.

This is how we set the listener for donut chart

```
segments.forEach(Consumer { segment: PieSegment ->
        segment.addIsSelectedChangeListener {

            drawColumnChart(clickedSliceProperties)

        }
    })
```

The method which draws the ColumnChart

```
private fun drawColumnChart(values: Array<Int>) {
    val xAxis: IAxis = sciChartBuilder.newNumericAxis().withGrowBy(0.15, 0.15).withLabelProvider(YearsLabelProvider()).build()
    val yAxis: IAxis = sciChartBuilder.newNumericAxis().withGrowBy(0.0, 0.0).build()

    xAxis.autoRange = AutoRange.Always
    yAxis.autoRange = AutoRange.Always

    val dataSeries: IXyDataSeries<Int, Int> = sciChartBuilder.newXyDataSeries(Int::class.javaObjectType, Int::class.javaObjectType).build()


    for (i in values.indices) {
        dataSeries.append(i, values[i])
    }

    val rSeries = sciChartBuilder.newColumnSeries()
            .withStrokeStyle(-0xdcdcdd, 0.4f)
            .withDataPointWidth(0.5)
            .withDataSeries(dataSeries)
            .withPaletteProvider(ColumnsPaletteProvider())
            .build()

    UpdateSuspender.using(lineChart) {
        lineChart.theme = R.style.SciChart_Bright_Spark
        Collections.addAll(lineChart.xAxes, xAxis)
        Collections.addAll(lineChart.yAxes, yAxis)
        Collections.addAll(lineChart.renderableSeries, rSeries)
        Collections.addAll(lineChart.chartModifiers, sciChartBuilder.newModifierGroupWithDefaultModifiers().build())
        sciChartBuilder.newAnimator(rSeries).withWaveTransformation().withInterpolator(DecelerateInterpolator()).withDuration(3000).withStartDelay(350).start()
    }
}
```

Trying to pass a different set of values to drawColumnChart() method this exception is thrown.

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AxisCollection.getAxisById('DefaultAxisId') returned more than one axis with the ID=DefaultAxisId. Please check you have assigned correct axis Ids when you have multiple axes in SciChart

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

This exception is thrown, because each axis in xAxes/yAxes collection should have unique id. Also you should have in mind that in case of multiple axes you also need to assign correct axis id for renderable series. Please take a look on [SciChart tutorial that how to add multiple axes into the chart.](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/current/webframe.html#Tutorial%2008%20-%20Adding%20Multiple%20Axis.html).

So in your case code for creation of axes should look like this:

```
val xAxis: IAxis = sciChartBuilder.newNumericAxis().withAxisId(uniqueXAxisId).withGrowBy(0.15, 0.15).withLabelProvider(YearsLabelProvider()).build()
val yAxis: IAxis = sciChartBuilder.newNumericAxis().withAxisId(uniqueYAxisId).withGrowBy(0.0, 0.0).build()
```

and code for creation of renderable series like this:

```
val rSeries = sciChartBuilder.newColumnSeries()
        .withXAxisId(uniqueXAxisId)
        .withYAxisId(uniqueYAxisId)
        .withStrokeStyle(-0xdcdcdd, 0.4f)
        .withDataPointWidth(0.5)
        .withDataSeries(dataSeries)
        .withPaletteProvider(ColumnsPaletteProvider())
        .build()
```

---

However if you want to update column values without adding new series, then just create and set xAxis, yAxis and renderable series once outside listener, store data series in private field and in listener update data series with new data instead of recreating it every time:

```
dataSeries.clear()
for (i in values.indices) {
    dataSeries.append(i, values[i])
}
```